# Kubuntu 16.04.1: Konsole: Cannot see underscore in the last line

Tags: 16.04, kde, konsole

The underscore character (_) is shown as space when in the last line of the Konsole.  Is there a way to get rid of this?

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem.
I fixed it by changing the font for Konsole.
Setting -> Current profile -> Appearance tab -> font

The font was Monospace when I cannot the underscore.
Now I am using Noto Mono.

I hope that your problem is fixed by same way.
Enjoy!

Comment: Sorry for the typo. -> The font was Monospace when I cannot see the underscore. Now I am using Noto Mono.